# Maven compilation error: Incompatible lists

Tags: java, maven-3

I want to null-check a List and assign it to a final class property:

```
private final ExcelDocument xls;
private final List<ValidationError> validationErrors;

public DefaultExaminationParser(ExcelDocument xls, List<ValidationError> validationErrors)
{
    this.xls = xls;
    this.validationErrors = validationErrors == null ? new ArrayList<>() : validationErrors;
}
```

The import is: `import java.util.List;` and `import java.util.ArrayList;`

The compiler in eclipse and maven is Java 1.8

My IDE (eclipse) does not show any problems with this line, but when I run a maven build it fails with following error:

> DefaultExaminationParser.java:[84,51] error: incompatible types: `List<? extends Object>` cannot be converted to `List<ValidationError>`

The ValidationError is defined as:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ValidationError implements Serializable, DetailInfo {
    [...]
}
```

I don't see any errors here. I can also run a unit test for this class without problems.

Comment: Are you sure that is the actual code snippet that causes the error? There is not even a `List<? extends Object>` involved in the snippet.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that constructor is at line 84?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that the compiler level for maven was set to 1.7 in one of the several parent pom files.

Used following snippet to set it explicitly to 1.8:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>utf8</encoding>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```